# Is C pointer only good for implementing data structures?

Tags: c, pointers

I have just begun using C everyday and was wondering, besides data structures (eg, link list, binary tree etc)  are there any other use for pointers? *Note: Edited*

Comment: I don't understand what this means. What do you think a "data structure" is? Pointers can be used for anything; they have an infinite number of uses.

Comment: code + data = programs in other words everything that you operate on is a data structure. The question is too vague.

Comment: What is a computer good for other than manipulating data structures?

Comment: @CodyGray, the question may not say so explicitly, but given the "just begun using C" I understand the OP to be using "data structures" in the sense of traditional data structures as taught in a data structures programming course: linked lists, trees, heaps, and so forth. Such structures are often the first explicit uses of pointers that a beginner encounters. It may be hard to remember a time when using pointers wasn't natural to you, but learning to use pointers requires a huge mental shift for someone who's never thought in those terms.

Comment: @Caleb: I didn't miss that part of the question. But there's no particularly good reason to consider a linked list or a tree a "data structure" any more than one should consider an "int" a data structure. This doesn't change whether one is a beginning programmer or a veteran. I didn't say "this question is stupid, it doesn't deserve an answer", I merely asked for clarification on how he is applying the phrase "data structures". I definitely learned about pointers to `int`s before I learned about linked lists.

Comment: @CodyGray: thats what alot of people say, but I haven't seen any unexpected usage of pointers, yet.

Comment: @CodyGray, Basic types like int and char are the building blocks of data structures, and they certainly store data, but they are not data structures in any commonly accepted definition of [tag:data-structure]. Asserting that int is as much a data structure as linked list is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C has no built-in method of passing by reference.  Pointers are a good way to implement that.

You need passing by reference if you want to:

- modify the arguments that you were given, for instance if your function has more than one return value.
- pass a large structure to a function without copying it entirely, which could be very wasteful in time and memory.

---

C also has no built-in variable-size data structures.  If you need an array whose size is only known at runtime, the only two ways of getting it are:

1. estimate the maximum size and always allocate it.
2. `malloc` it, which will give you a pointer to work with.

Obviously, option 1 is bad because:

1. it's wasteful, if you rarely need the maximum size.
2. if the maximum needs to change, you have to recompile.

This leaves you with option 2, which requires pointers.  This would not necessarily be true if C had references, but as I said before, it doesn't.

I could probably think of many other uses if I gave it more time.

---

You can use function pointers to wrap a common functionality around various functions.

Comment: But...what else would you need to pass by reference except "data structures"?

Comment: @Cody: extra output parameters, WinAPI uses this a lot, especially in IO code to return number of bytes read/written.

Comment: @Cody Gray: if you need a function that needs to return more than one value, a common way to do that is to send it output variables by reference, which the function then updates.  If you don't have references, you can use pointers instead.

Comment: @Necrolis: That's a good answer; you should post it. Pointers are about the only way to implement a function that returns multiple values in C.

Comment: Just to add on @Nathan's comment, dynamic arrays are another common usage

Comment: @Cody: I would, but its of little use now as others have covered that :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are, for example, pointers can point to functions, so you can write generic algorithms which are calling a function depending on your variable types. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer

The most useful ability, besides iterating through data structures, is to have function parameters which you are able to change. A very basic example:

```
void increment(int a)
{
    a = a+1;
}
```

will not alter the value of `a`, because inside of the function you work only on a *copy* of your variable.

However, if you use a pointer instead, it will work:

```
void increment(int *a)
{
    *a = *a+1;
}
```

Of course, you have to call it like this: `increment(&a)`.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are memory addresses. Whenever you want to refer to something that's stored somewhere in memory, you use a pointer. So, you might use pointers to refer to data, and not necessarily just as part of a data structure -- you'd also use pointers to locate a buffer filled with the contents of a file, or to remember particular locations in that buffer. Every time you `malloc()` a chunk of memory or declare an array you're using a pointer. As several others have pointed out, you can also use pointers to functions -- a function name by itself is actually a pointer. Pointers are also used to maintain critical data structures that make your program work, particularly the stack and the heap. Many devices connected to the microprocessor are memory mapped, which means that you access them by reading or writing certain memory locations.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers in C serve three main purposes:

- Faking pass-by-reference semantics.  Since C passes all function arguments by value, the only way for a function to modify the value of the argument is to pass a pointer to the argument:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  void foo(int *a, int b)
  {    
    *a = 1;
    b = 2;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    printf("before: x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    // output should be "before: x = 0, y = 0"
    foo(&a, b);
    printf("after:  x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    // output should be "after:  x = 1, y = 0"
    return 0;
  }
  ```

  Tracking dynamically allocated memory.  The memory allocation functions `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` all return pointer values:

  ```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  ...
  // Dynamically allocate a block of N integers and assign
  // the resulting pointer to arr
  int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * N);
  ```

  And, finally, creating dynamic data structures such as lists, trees, queues, etc.  Note that you don't *need* to use pointers to do this; generations of Fortran programmers used arrays as their "heap" and array indices as pointers.

In systems and embedded programming, pointers also allow you direct access to, say, video memory, shared memory buffers,network ports, etc.

Answer (score 1):

They can also be used when working with arrays and in pointer arithmetic, and of course, to ensure that you don't deep copy when passing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[Function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) can be very useful.

Answer (score -1):

pointer can be used for a whole lot of things,and most importantly access memory locations directly.

Comment: And why is it important to be able to access memory locations directly? This answer is too broad. It doesn't provide me with any useful information.

Comment: <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29#Uses>

Comment: I didn't ask you to tell me what a pointer was. I asked you to expand your answer so that it's not worthless. Linking to a Wikipedia article is not an answer. Neither is your single sentence. There'd be no point in having this site if you could just link everyone to Wikipedia instead of answering their questions.

Comment: ok,being on good side you may need to access mem locations for hardware communication,and being on bad side you may need to access memory locations to rough up systems.These are just simplest possible examples but there may be lots more...